# Nginx add_header Link not parsed by Lighthouse

Tags: nginx, http-headers

I'm trying to investigate why Google isn't indexing some pages (allegedly, because they redirect) and, when using Lighthouse to check an example page, I see the following:

```
Error parsing link header (Unexpected character "h" at offset 0): https://doi.org/XXX/YYY; rel="cite-as"
```

The relevant Nginx configuration contains this:

```
set $cite_link 'https://doi.org/XXX/YYY; rel="cite-as"'; 
if ($http_accept = 'application/json') {
  add_header Link $cite_link;
  # Some other things...
}
```

What's wrong with this link? I'm not sure if it's related to the alleged redirection, but it would be useful to be able to fix it in case it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the [specification for `Link` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Link):

> The URI (absolute or relative) must be enclosed between < and >:

Add the enclosing `< >` required by the standard and try again.